# How to do arithmetic operations on 2 different variables and store in one variable to give as input in POST API payload

Tags: python-2.7, api, robotframework

> I'm hitting the GET API and storing the **Run-time Inventory Value** in variable **${quantity1}**
>
> Next I'm checking condition for the value in **${quantity1}** i.e. if 
>   **${quantity1} > 4 and ${Itemid} == 1** then the Robot Framework would hit the POST API to update the Inventory value to less than threshold (i.e 4)

[Reference to the Robot Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nBYL.png)

> I want a way out of how can I perform an arithmetic operation say for example 
>   **${newQuantity} = ${quantity1} - 4**
>
> And pass this value in ${newQuantity} in POST API (tag name - quantity)

### Post API Payload

```
{
  "distributionPointId":7,
  "menuItemId":1,
  "quantity":-11,
  "transactionDoneBy":11,
  "transactionType":1,
  "reasonId":11,
  "barcode":""
}
```

Please can anyone help me with this so I can solve the problem
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use the Evaluate keyword from BuiltIn library.
It executes a Python expression and returns the result.

`${newQuantitiy}=    Evaluate    $Quantity1 - 4`

Be aware that you can use Variables in `Evaluate` in two different ways.
${Quantity1}  would put the textual value of variable to the string that is evaluated.
$Quantity1 uses the  variable itself in the expression.

In this special case it would not make any difference.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate

However there are also multiple different way to do a calculation!

Extended Variable Syntax:

Just use the Varibale ${Quantitiy1 - 4}
Or assignt it to a new one. `${newQuantiti}=    Set Variable     ${Quantity1 - 4}`

See: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it worked for me. There is a problem I'm facing on passing ${newQuantitiy after **Evaluate** in POST API, it is generating the 200 response with the exact number after **${newQuantitiy}=    Evaluate    $Quantity1 - 4** but it is not impacting the quantity. Is that a problem with the API or Robot code ?

```${newQuantity}= Evaluate ${quantity1} - 4 
Create Session Update_inventory_details ${Base_URL}    
${body}= Create Dictionary distributionPointId=7 menuItemId=1 quantity=-${newQuantity} transactionDoneBy=11 transactionType=2 reasonId=12 barcode=null
```

Comment: well the issue is solved now.. converted the new value to string 
```${Fquantity}= Convert To String ${newQuantity}```

and then had passed the value as string in POST API payload 

```${body}= Create Dictionary distributionPointId=7 menuItemId=1 quantity=${-${Fquantity}} transactionDoneBy=11 transactionType=2 reasonId=12 barcode=null```